# How to set permanent mtu size for ppp0

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vpn, mtu, pptp

every time I connect to my VPN, I should run

```
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
```

How could I make it permanent?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your custom script 
at this address :  `/etc/network/if-up.d`,

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi
```

finally make executable and enjoy from your life ...

Comment: What should be the script name? doe it matter?

Comment: Doesnt work for ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to apply Farshad's solution on ubuntu 16, and it wasn't working.

Only small fix was needed there - remove `sudo` from your script, because everything inside `/etc/network/if-up.d/` dir is already run as root user.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi
```